# my form in rails 3 rendering multiple times photos for a model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

the problem is that I have a form that normally should render photos of current car and it does so but it renders them multiple times.. like this: I have 5 photos for car_id 2 and on screen I have 5 times these photos displayed.

12345
12345
12345
12345
12445

If I add a photo, then it will be diplayed 6 times. what is the problem and how can I solve it, I've tried a lot of: replace this, replace that but nothing.

**Here is a piece of the form itself**

```
<%= form_for @car, :html => { :method => :put }, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
...
...
    <% for photo in @car.uploads %>
    <div style="width:750px !important;">
          <%= f.fields_for :uploads do |photo_fields| %>
            <%unless photo_fields.object.new_record? %>
                <div style="width:150px;float:left;">
                  <%= image_tag(photo_fields.object.photo.url(:thumb)) %>
                  <p><%= photo_fields.check_box :_destroy %>  Delete item</p>
                </div>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
      </div>  
....
...
<% end %>
```

**and the console:**

```
Started GET "/cars/2/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Nov 06 22:50:17 +0200 2011
  Processing by CarsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (4.1ms)  SHOW TABLES
  Car Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `cars`.* FROM `cars` WHERE `cars`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `cars`.* FROM `cars` WHERE `cars`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Carname Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `carnames`.* FROM `carnames`
  Carmodel Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `carmodels`.* FROM `carmodels`
Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Upload Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `uploads`.* FROM `uploads` WHERE (`uploads`.car_id = 2)
  Carname Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `carnames`.* FROM `carnames` WHERE `carnames`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Carmodel Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `carmodels`.* FROM `carmodels` WHERE `carmodels`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
Rendered uploads/_upload.html.erb (8.1ms)
Rendered cars/_show.html.erb (2.7ms)
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_id
Rendered cars/_form.html.erb (460.6ms)
Rendered welcome/_sliderempty.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered welcome/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the for loop, `fields_for` already iterates over the photos so you iterate twice you get the photos twice.

In response to your comment: try to pass the collection explicitly like:

`<%= f.fields_for :uploads, @car.uploads do |photo_fields| %>`

So here you go:

```
<%= form_for @car, :html => { :method => :put }, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
...
...
    <div style="width:750px !important;">
          <%= f.fields_for :uploads, @car.uploads do |photo_fields| %>
            <%unless photo_fields.object.new_record? %>
                <div style="width:150px;float:left;">
                  <%= image_tag(photo_fields.object.photo.url(:thumb)) %>
                  <p><%= photo_fields.check_box :_destroy %>  Delete item</p>
                </div>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
      </div>  
....
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: no, this results in a  undefined method `fields' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xb542b69c>  error

Comment: by the way: the error says you try to call `f.fields` and NOT `f.fields_for`!

Comment: still rendering multiple photos.. here is the full code from form, may be will be more helpfull  http://pastie.org/2822209

Comment: in your code you still have the `for` loop... maybe you want to do this just __before__ the `fields_for`:  `<h1><%= @car.uploads.length %></h1>` (for checking how many cars are stored in the model itself)

Comment: you mean that it is possble that I have in database more uploads stored for this car and that's the reason of displaying it wrong? They have exactly the number I uploaded. meaning 5 photos for each car, I have cheked using this code, and in database too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4766/discussion-between-sled-and-rmagnum2002)

Comment: All right, I got it -  you where right, I've been doing twice a {for}, I just removed the <% for photo in @car.uploads %> and it's all done now. Thanks for your time.